# How to append div dynamically after selecting any option from dropdown in JSP JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

[image: I am getting output as shown in picture.]
I have a dropdown list of all cities. I want to implement where I should be able to select any city from list and after selecting any city name, it should get append in div dynamically. I have implemented in this way:

```
<select class="floating-select" name="city" id="vendorcitydd" 
       onchange="setdeliverycity()">
    <c:forEach items="${citylist}" var="allcity">
        <option value="${allcity.delivercityid}">${allcity.city}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<div class="col-12">
    <h5>Delivery Cities</h5>
        <div id="citydivid" class=""></div>
</div>
    
    function setdeliverycity(){
            var userid = document.getElementById('vendordeliveryid').value;
            var delivercityid = document.getElementById('vendorcitydd').value;
            var url = "../api/setdeliverycity";
            $.post(url,{
                userid : userid,
                delivercityid : delivercityid,
            }, function(data, status) {
                if (data.status == "OK") {
                    if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                        var citydiv = "";   
                        var citylist = data.response.city;
                        var citylistlength = citylist.length;
                        if(citylistlength > 0){
                            for(var i = 0 ; i < citylistlength; i++) {
                                    citydiv = citydiv+"<div>"+citylist+" &nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i> 
                                                               </div>";
                                }
                        }else{
                            citydiv = citydiv+"<div style=\"text-align: center; float: left; margin-left: 
                               40%; font-size: medium; font-weight: bolder; background: blanchedalmond;\"> 
                               <span>Choose city from list</span></div>";
                        }
                        document.getElementById('citydivid').innerHTML = citydiv;
                    } else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            }); 
        }
```

But there is some problem in my script. When I select any city then in div tag only that city get appended according to it's existence in database. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: your problem statement is not that clear. Can you rephrase the issue you are facing.

Comment: the for loop is wrong. you are using "citylist" but it must be citylist[i].

Comment: I tried that way also. I tried for citylist[i] too, but did not worked.

Comment: Can you show output of `data` ? Also , please elaborate more on your issue .

Comment: Solved. Thank you. but next thing is I need to store all cities in database